# show that f is not darboux integrable on [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

[image]

Show that f is not Darboux integrable on [0,1]

I have a problem getting a headstart for this question. I don't know any direction in order to prove this question. I know that a bounded function is Darboux integrable if and only if the lower integral = upper integral.

Comment: Do you have definitions for the lower integral and the upper integral?

Comment: Lower integral= sup{L(f;P): P is a partition of [a,b]}
Upper integral= inf{U(f;P): P is a partition of [a,b]}

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability

Answer (score 2):

For any partition you know that each part has a point on the upper curve, and using those gives a lower bound on the upper sum. As the partition size goes to 0, that lower bound must tend to the Darboux integral of the upper curve, since the upper curve is integrable. Likewise, the lower sum has an upper bound that tends to the integral of the lower curve. Thus if the upper and lower curves have different integrals, the original function will not be integrable.

More precisely:

Let $S = \mathbb{Q}$

Let $T = \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$

Let $g = x \mapsto \max(\sin(x),\cos(x))$

Let $h = x \mapsto \min(\sin(x),\cos(x))$

As $|P| \to 0$ where $P$ is a partition of $[0,1]$,

$P$ is some ordered list $( x_k : k \in [0..n] )$

Let $Q = ( y_k : k \in [1..n] )$ be such that:

For each $k \in [1..n]$,

$f(y_k) = g(y_k)$ for some $y_k \in [x_{k-1},x_k]$ because $S,T$ are dense in $[x_{k-1},x_k]$

Then $(P,Q)$ is a tagged partition of $[0,1]$ and $|(P,Q)| \to 0$

Thus $U(f,P) \ge R(f,(P,Q)) \to \int_{[0,1]} g$

For any $ε > 0$,

For any partition $P$ of $[0,1]$,

Let $P'$ be a sufficiently fine refinement of $P$ such that (by the above):

$U(f,P') \ge R(f,(P',Q)) \ge \int_{[0,1]} g - ε$ for some tags $Q$ for $P'$

$U(f,P) \ge U(f,P') \ge \int_{[0,1]} g - ε$

Therefore $U(f) \ge \int_{[0,1]} g - ε$

Therefore $U(f) \ge \int_{[0,1]} g$

Likewise $L(f) \le \int_{[0,1]} h$

Comment: Yes I got you, the problem is with the rational and irrational part. I often get stuck with this portion.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.. do you get the solution? For any partition, each part has a point on the upper curve precisely because the values of $x$ for which $f(x)$ is on the upper curve is dense in $[0,1]$, and the same for the lower curve, because both $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$ are dense in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Um, I think I roughly get the idea that you are talking about, do you have any sort of mathematical working ? It would be easier that way. Thanks!

Comment: Okay give me a while to add some working in.

Comment: By the way, it's usually not the part concerning the rational and irrational tags that will go wrong. Look very very carefully through the argument I gave. Just a slight change will probably invalidate the whole proof.